gradle refresh dependency isn't taking effect
I've added a new repository in my gradle project and am trying to force the build to refresh dependencies to pick up from this new repo:
my build.gradle is updated with this repo:
repositories {
   maven { url "https://new repo url/new repo"  }

and my build is updated with the following:
      ./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies
      ./gradlew --refresh-dependencies 

the build is still picking up from the old repos. I've also tried deleting the cache using rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/ but it doesn't seem to help
